# Error ao tentar identificar se uma string é igual a um dos valores de uma array

Tags: node.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = (client, msg, args) => {
    msg.delete();
    let type = args[0];
    let types = ['available', 'idle', 'dnd', 'invisible']
    if(!type === types[0] || types[1] || types[2] || types[3]) return msg.channel.send(new Discord.RichEmbed().setAuthor('Error').setDescription('Sintaxe errada.'))

}
```

Basicamente, quando eu executo o comando de forma errada, o embed é enviado,mas quando eu executo de forma certo, mesmo assim o embed é enviado.

Alguém pra ajudar? :)

Comment: Como o próprio nome diz este é o StackOverflow **em português**, traduza sua pergunta ou poste-a no site internacional.

Comment: Desculpa... vou trocar.

Comment: Não existe uma comparação do tipo `variavel === 'A' || 'B'`. A resposta dada abaixo está correta, mas se você precisar fazer um `if` do tipo, deve fazer `variavel === 'A' || variavel === 'B'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para verificar se uma `string` está contida em um `array` você pode usar a função [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains) do `array`:

```
...
if (types.includes(type))...
...
```

> [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)
>
> O método `includes()` determina se um `array` contém um determinado elemento, retornando `true` ou `false` apropriadamente.

Comment: Eu sabia disso, mas não tinha pensando em usa-la neste contexto. Muito obrigado!